# Allocating memory thorugh malloc for std::string array not working

Tags: c++, string, heap-memory

I'm having trouble allocating memory on the heap for an array of strings. Allocating with new works but malloc segfaults each time. The reason I want to use malloc in the first place is that I don't want to call the constructor unnecessarily.

This works fine

```
std::string* strings = new std::string[6];
```

This doesn't

```
std::string* strings = (std::string *)malloc(sizeof(std::string[6]));
```

---

One thing I've noticed is that the first variant (using new) allocates 248 bytes of memory while the second allocates only 240. This 8 byte difference is constant no matter the size of the array from what I've gathered and I cannot find what the source of the difference is.

Here's the whole code that segfaults.

```
#include <iostream>

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    return malloc(size);
}

void* operator new [](size_t size)
{
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    return malloc(size);
}

int main() {
    std::string* strings = new std::string[6];
    strings = (std::string *)malloc(sizeof(std::string[6]));

    strings[0] = std::string("test");

    return 0;
}
```

Another thing I've noticed is that the above code seems to work if I use memset after malloc to set all of the bytes I allocated with malloc to 0. I don't understand where the 8 byte difference comes from if this works and also why this variant works at all. Why would it work just because I set all of the bytes to 0?

Comment: Don't do manual memory allocation.  What you want is a `std::vector<std::string>`.  You can then `reserve` the space you need and no constructors will be called.

Comment: Using C++ classes with C allocation functions will not work if you don't know what you are doing. And `strings[0] = std::string("test");` especially is broken, because you never constructed any valid `std::string` objects in the memory you allocated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc()` only allocates raw memory, but it does not construct any objects inside of that memory.

`new` and `new[]` both allocate memory and construct objects.

If you really want to use `malloc()` to create an array of C++ objects (which you really SHOULD NOT do!), then you will have to call the object constructors yourself using [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), and also call the object destructors yourself before freeing the memory, eg:

```
std::string* strings = static_cast<std::string*>(
    malloc(sizeof(std::string) * 6)
);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    new (&strings[i]) std::string;
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    strings[i].~std::string();
}

free(strings);
```

In C++11 and C++14, you should use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) to help calculate the necessary size of the array memory, eg:

```
using string_storage = std::aligned_storage<sizeof(std::string), alignof(std::string)>::type;

void *buffer = malloc(sizeof(string_storage) * 6);

std::string* strings = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(buffer);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    new (&strings[i]) std::string;
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    strings[i].~std::string();
}

free(buffer);
```

In C++17 and later, you should use [`std::aligned_alloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) instead of `malloc()` directly, eg:

```
std::string* strings = static_cast<std::string*>(
    std::aligned_alloc(alignof(std::string), sizeof(std::string) * 6)
);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    new (&strings[i]) std::string;
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    strings[i].~std::string();
}

std::free(strings);
```

Comment: But am I not calling the constructor here `strings[0] = std::string("test");` ? Why isn't this enough?

Comment: `std::string("test")` constructs a *separate* temporary `string` object, which you are then assigning to the `string` object stored in `strings[0]` via the `string::operator=` assignment operator - except that the target object wasn't constructed by `malloc()`, thus you are invoking *undefined behavior* by assigning to an *uninitialized* object.

Comment: @Redex: In that line, you are calling the constructor on a temporary object and then assigning that object to `strings[0]`. Therefore, you are calling the function `strings[0].operator=`, because `std::string` overloads the `=` operator. Calling this function requires the underlying object's fields to be valid, i.e. constructed. I don't know whether the behavior is also undefined for classes that do not overload the `=` operator. My guess is that assigning to an uninitialized object is only guaranteed to work with [POD types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel all copyable/movable class types have an overloaded `operator=`, either implicitly generated by the compiler or explicitly written by the user. And *technically* `malloc()`'ing an array of POD types does not create valid objects either, at least prior to C++20 with the introduction of implicit lifetimes of trivial types, but most earlier compilers let you get away with it.

Answer (score 5):

Allocating via `new` means the constructor is run. Please always use `new` and `delete` with C++ classes (and `std::string` is a C++ class), whenever you can.

When you do `malloc()` / `free()`, only memory allocation is done, constructor (destructor) is not run. This means, the object is not initialized. Technically you might still be able to use placement `new` (i.e., `new(pointer) Type`) to initialize it, but it's better and more conformant to use classic `new`.

If you wanted to allocate multiple objects, that's what containers are for. Please use them. Multiple top-grade engineers work on `std::vector<>`, `std::array<>`, `std::set<>`, `std::map<>` to work and be optimal - it's *very* hard to beat them in performance, stability or other metrics and, even if you do, the next coder at the same company needs to learn into your specific data structures. So it's suggested not to use custom and locally implemented allocations where a container could be used, unless for a very strong reason (or, of course, didactic purposes).

Comment: "*Please always use `new` and `delete` with C++ classes..., whenever you can*" - or better, never use `new`  and `delete` directly at all. Modern practices advise that when you need to create objects dynamically, use smart pointer factories like `std::make_unique()` or `std::make_shared()`, or use dynamic-sized containers like `std::vector`. Let the standard library handle the memory management for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There are levels of removing the bad practices. What I wrote is first step (compared to `malloc`), what you wrote is the next step :).